# find a line and read/display the next line in text document C#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have this code so far. It looks through a text document and displays lines with the word `word` in them. I want to make it skip that line and display the next one in the text document, how do I do that?

e.g. it looks thought the text document and finds a line with the word "word" in it and then displays the line that comes after it no other line

```
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("word"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

}

file.Close();
```

Comment: Unclear and incomplete. What should happen with `counter` ?

Comment: You just want to write lines except the lines contains `word` string? Your question is not clear I think..

Comment: Are trivial logic problems even on topic?

Comment: You mean you copied that code from somewhere and now you don't now how to reverse an if-clause?

Comment: e.g. it looks thought the text document and finds a line with the word "word" in it and then displays the line that comes after it no other line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write the line following an occurence of `word` in a line, try this:

```
int counter = 0;
bool writeNextLine = false;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (writeNextLine) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line); 
    }
    writeNextLine = line.Contains("word");    
    counter++;
}

file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will show all the lines except empty lines and lines with the word "word"

```
using (var rdr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\text.txt"))
{
     while (!(rdr.EndOfStream))
     {
         var line = rdr.ReadLine();
         if (!(line.Contains("word")) && (line != String.Empty))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(line);
         }
     }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should display all lines after those that contain `"word"`.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("word"))
    {
        if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    counter++;
}
file.Close();
```